# Is it possible to implement recursive paths using react router version 2?

Tags: reactjs, redux, routes, react-router

I am working with a project using react router version 15.4 and react router version 2.
I need to implement recursive paths using react router version 2 which would look exactly like the example here. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/recursive-paths
I cannot migrate to react router 4 at the moment.
Is it possible to implement the same functionality in version 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. v2/3 rely on a static, top-level route configuration.

Recursive routes are only possible in 4.0 because of the dynamic nature of React's component tree.

Comment: That was helpful. Thanks